# Add text to each value while looping thru and printing them in a array?

Tags: bash, array

I'm trying to add a text to every value in array while I loop thru them.

I tried this:

```
for value in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "--" "$value"
done
```

It will only add "--" one time. And that's in the beginning of the output.

I've tried printf also, like this:

```
printf "%s--" "${array[@]}"
```

Same result.

I add my values like this:

```
array+="1"
array+="2"
array+="3"
```

I declare my array like this:

```
array=()
```

Also tried:

```
declare -a array
```

Is this the correct behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to an array, you need to use parentheses:

```
array+=(1)
array+=(2)
```

The way you used you added all the values to the first element of the array.